# Wrong page number in TOC for endnote

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, page-numbering, blank-page, enotez

When I set the list heading of an endnote part to `\chapter` in order to have a page break, it occur a bad pagenumber of the endnote part in the TOC.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enotez}

\setenotez{list-heading=\chapter*{#1},totoc=section}



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\tableofcontents
\endnote{foo}

\printendnotes


\end{document}
```

### Rendering

So the Notes page is correctly begin in a new dedicated page as desired:
[image: Rendering of the Note page]

As you see, it is in this example set in the page 5.

But unfortunatly, the table of content mark it as in page 3:

[image: TOC showing Note page on page 3]

### Guessess

My guesses it’s because the `\\addcontentsline{toc}` start immediatly at the `\printendnotes` call and doesn’t wait the `\cleardoublepage` takes effect.

So, how to make the Note page number apears at the TOC at his real beginning page?

Comment: You can simply add a `\cleardoublepage` explicitly, right before `\printendnotes`.

Comment: Yes @Jinwen it’s the solution. If you write an answer, I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: I believe someone else might be able to come up with a more clever solution (or fix), since this is certainly not the expected behavior for this command. Adding `\cleardoublepage` is just my lucky guess.

Answer (score 0):

I should put `\cleardoublepage` before `\\addcontentsline{toc}` to ensure page number.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enotez}

\setenotez{list-heading=\chapter*{#1},totoc=section}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter% <<<
  \tableofcontents

  \mainmatter% <<<
  \lipsum[1]


  \endnote{foo}

  \backmatter% <<<
  \printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: contents]
[image: lipsum]
[image: endnote]